# How to remove the mentioned string in a optimized way?

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have a problem where I have to remove some unwanted characters from the string .
For example if the string is **Hi Uim IMAGE [rofl]test** then I want it to be like **Hi Uim rofl test**. I donot want to  hardcode IMAGE[ and than again a closing ] using replace of string. Instead of `IMAGE`, there can be any word in ALLCAPS.

I have written something like the below but would prefer if this can be done in a better way .

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "";
        String in = "Hi Uim IMAGE [rofl] test IMAGE [rofl] notify the bull";
        String[] split = in.split("IMAGE \\[(.*?)\\]");
        System.out.println(split);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("IMAGE \\[(.*?)\\]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
        int i = 0;
        while (m.find()) {
            String group = m.group(1);
            System.out.println(group);
            test = test + split[i++] + group;
        }
        for (int var = i; var < split.length; var++) {
            test = test + split[var];
        }
        System.out.println(test);
    }

}
```

This has a problem like I have to loop through it. Is there any better way to do this.

Comment: *I donot want to hardcode IMAGE* - so what is the pattern like?

Comment: I mean the regular expression should somehow detect  IMAGE[ ] and it should only remove  sorry for not being clear

Comment: *should somehow detect IMAGE[ ]* is not any clearer: do you mean a word in ALLCAPS followed with `[...]`? Or do you have a list of these words?

Comment: Yes But would like the word inside the [ ] to stay

Comment: Try `s.replaceAll("(\\s*)\\b[A-Z]+\\s*\\[([^\\]\\[]*)]", "$1$2")`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VFV4ub/1/).

Comment: BTW your current code can be rewritten as `String test = in.replaceAll("IMAGE \\[(.*?)\\]", "$1");` since `$1` in *replacement* section represents content of group 1. If you want to use other words instead of `IMAGE` but still want them to be capital replace it with `[A-Z]+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks it works .Can you put it as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
in = in.replaceAll("\\b[A-Z]+\\s*\\[([^\\]\\[]*)]", "$1");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VFV4ub/2)

**Regex details**

- `\b[A-Z]+` - a word boundary and 1+ uppercase ASCII letters
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^\]\[]*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.